# How to use 2 DataProviders with 2 data types with 1 Factory in overrriding contructor

Tags: testng-dataprovider

I have two `DataProvider`s which should set the datas with two data types (long & double) with one factory, but when I run the code the tests take different data types like, double & int.

```
public class FactoryTest {

    @Factory(dataProvider ="doubleData")
    public Object[] getArithmeticDoubleFunctions(double firstNumber,double secondNumber)
    {
        System.out.println(String.format("Generate test for user: %s %s", firstNumber, secondNumber));
        return new Object[]{new ArithmeticFunctionsTest(firstNumber,secondNumber)};
    }

    @Factory(dataProvider ="longData")
    public Object[] getArithmeticLongFunctions(long firstNumber1,long secondNumber1)
    {
        System.out.println(String.format("Generate test for user: %s %s", firstNumber1, secondNumber1));
        return new  Object[]{new ArithmeticFunctionsTest( firstNumber1,secondNumber1)};
    }
}

@DataProvider(name="longData")
public Object[][] arithmeticDoubleData() {
    return new Object[][]{{10, 12}, {-1,-1},{-1,23},{0,1},{-1,2}};
}
@DataProvider(name="doubleData")
public Object[][] arithmeticLongData() {
    return new Object[][]{{10.0, 12.3}, {-1.1,-1},{-1.7,23.2},{0,1.2},{-1.1,2.2}};
}

public ArithmeticFunctionsTest(long firstNumber, long secondNubmer) {
    this.firstLongNumber = firstNumber;
    this.secondLongNumber = secondNubmer;
}

public ArithmeticFunctionsTest(double firstNumber, double secondNumber) {
    this.firstDoubleNumber = firstNumber;
    this.secondDoubleNumber = secondNumber;
}

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {
    calculator = new Calculator();
}

@Test
public void testLongSum() {
    Assert.assertEquals(calculator.sum(firstLongNumber, secondLongNumber), firstLongNumber + secondLongNumber);
    System.out.println(firstLongNumber+" "+secondLongNumber+" Long sum");
}

@Test
public void testDoubleSum() {
    Assert.assertEquals(calculator.sum(firstDoubleNumber, secondDoubleNumber), firstDoubleNumber + secondDoubleNumber);
    System.out.println(firstDoubleNumber+" "+secondDoubleNumber+"double sum");
}
```

The test with `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` types should have only the data providers with needed types, but types are mixing.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FactoryTest {
    @Factory(dataProvider ="doubleData")
    public Object[] getArithmeticDoubleFunctions(double firstNumber,double secondNumber)
    {
        System.out.println(String.format("Generate test for user: %s %s", firstNumber, secondNumber));
        return new Object[]{new ArithmeticFunctionsTest(firstNumber,secondNumber)};
    }
    @Factory(dataProvider ="longData")
    public Object[] getArithmeticLongFunctions(long firstNumber1,long secondNumber1)
    {
        System.out.println(String.format("Generate test for user: %s %s", firstNumber1, secondNumber1));
        return new  Object[]{new ArithmeticFunctionsTest( firstNumber1,secondNumber1)};
    }

    @DataProvider(name="longData")
    public Object[][] arithmeticDoubleData() {
        return new Object[][]{{10, 12}, {-1,-1},{-1,23},{0,1},{-1,2}};
    }
    @DataProvider(name="doubleData")
    public Object[][] arithmeticLongData() {
        return new Object[][]{{10.0, 12.3}, {-1.1,-1},{-1.7,23.2},{0,1.2},{-1.1,2.2}};
    }
```